# How to remove first element from array once uploaded Java Server Side Code

Tags: java, arrays, file-upload

I have a multiple file upload and when i select two files and the last, it duplicates the first file twice and the last file once. When i select three files, it creates the first file three times, the second file two times and the last file once. It looks like its an issue with my array and not removing the file uploaded from it through each iteration? Can anyone help fixing this

```
private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "C://temp//";

@RequestMapping(value = { "/fileUpload" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile( @RequestParam("number") String number, @RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile[] files, MultipartHttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{       

    for (MultipartFile file : files) {

    try {
        File directory = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER + number);
        logger.info(directory.toString());
                if (! directory.exists()){
                    directory.mkdir();
                    logger.info("directory created");
                  }
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            logger.info(bytes.toString());
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(new Date());
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((10 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + number + "//" + file.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[0] + " - " +  timeStamp + randomNum + "." + file.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[1]);
            logger.info(path.toString());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
            logger.info("You have successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
            //return("File Uploaded");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        logger.error("Failed to upload file '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'", e);
        //return("File Not Uploaded");
    }

}
    return "redirect:/fileUpload";
}
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. I would think your issue is somewhere else. Of course you could ignore duplicates, but if it were me, I'd rather try if I could solve the problem at its source.

Comment: Do you think its not removing the uploaded file from the array after each iteration? if so, how do i remove the file from the array after each loop.

Comment: Your enhanced for loop should proces each array element only once, so there should be no need for removing the element after upload. If in doubt, log the length of the array and compare with the expected.

Comment: 2017-04-18 15:29:45.292 INFO  c.g.o.i.controller.AjaxController.404 -Length Of Array: 1 
2017-04-18 15:29:45.293 INFO  c.g.o.i.controller.AjaxController.410 - C:\temp\600000\Capture - 2017041815299.JPG 
2017-04-18 15:29:45.299 INFO  c.g.o.i.controller.AjaxController.412 - You have successfully uploaded 'Capture.JPG' 

2017-04-18 15:29:45.341 INFO  c.g.o.i.controller.AjaxController.404 - Length Of Array: 2 
2017-04-18 15:29:45.342 INFO  c.g.o.i.controller.AjaxController.410 - C:\temp\600000\Capture - 2017041815292.JPG

Comment: Looks like its done twice, as I only selected the image Capture.JPG once ?

Comment: Looks to me like your method is called twice, one with an array of length 1 and one with an array of length 2. I cannot tell how that can happen. Seems to confirm your issue is outside the method?

Comment: The issue is when I add the timestamp and random number to the file. This has been removed and works.